# Can't boot, new usb device found

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

When trying to boot into the Ubuntu live usb, I get `new usb device found idvendor=1d6b idproduct=0003`, and it hangs there, refusing to boot. Ubuntu 14.04 booting into install or live mode, uefi and legacy 
How can I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have set the boot order to first look at the USB drive. Another option might be to restore the normal boot order and then enter the menu for selecting the boot device.

On most platforms there is a hotkey for doing this, but it varies a lot. It is usually something like F2, F12, DEL, holding down Ctrl or something similar.

Try looking up your platform to get the right hotkey. There is a change that this may work a bit better. If it doesn't, the error is probably with the USB image or some motherboard settings.

Comment: I am booting from a liveusb, using the boot menu. I have it set to first boot from my hdd

Comment: And sometimes it gets to `new usb device strings: Mfr=3, product=2, SerialNumber`

Comment: As far as I know, those are not error messages, so don't focus too much on those. I think the issue then is the USB stick itself. Could you try downloading a new image and burn it on a new USB stick?

Comment: sure, I'll try that now

Comment: Same result, and while I know that it's not an error message, that's where it hangs, so something is wrong

Comment: Any thoughts? I'm still having this problem

Comment: Have you tried disabling Secure boot? Be careful when experimenting with this though.

Comment: what would that do? I've tried booting into EFI and gpt

Comment: You can perhaps take a look at this question and answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/653583/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-toshiba-satellite-c850-19z/653589#653589

Comment: that's not what's happening, though