# How to install Ubuntu on Toshiba Satellite c850-19z

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

My computer is using UEFI and is running Windows 8.

I've tried install Ubuntu before but I only got as far as putting it on a USB
(using universal USB installer). But when I go to the boot manager on UEFI and put the USB port first before my hard-drive nothing happens and it just boots back into Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a case of **Secure Boot**, which is a security mechanism added by hardware vendors in collaboration with Microsoft to only allowed the system to boot from approved ISO images.

This mechanism can be a challenge when a user wants to install Ubuntu. Solutions depend on the UEFI in use, but it might entail disabling Secure Boot inside UEFI and then try again.

Be aware though that making changes in the BIOS is not without risk. If you decide to do it, it is a very good idea to write every changed setting down to be able to set it back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

As Zilvador says, this *could* be a Secure Boot issue; however, Ubuntu *should* support Secure Boot, so I suspect that one of two other things is happening:

- **Improperly-created USB drive** -- Assuming no changes to a stock computer, you'll need a USB drive with an EFI boot loader installed on it (including Ubuntu's Secure Boot tool, which is called *Shim*). Some tools for creating bootable USB drives won't copy these files, though, or will copy them only when certain options are set. Thus, you might need to try another tool, or change the options in the tool you're using.
- **Wrong option selected in boot manager** -- Most EFI boot managers (the displays you see when you hit a function key to choose what medium to boot) show two options for removable disks. One option includes the string "UEFI" and the other doesn't. These boot in EFI mode and in BIOS mode, respectively. Depending on firmware settings and how you prepared the disk, you might need to select one boot mode or the other -- EFI mode, if you want to install alongside Windows that's also in EFI mode. If you select the wrong mode, the disk might fail to boot, especially if it lacks the boot loader for the mode you chose (see the preceding point).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [this](https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale=en_US) tool to create a bootable USB. Make sure to select GPT partition scheme for UEFI comuters on second field.